# Django authentication user login

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

`I'm encountering an issue with user authentication in my Django project. I have a custom user model for doctors **`Doctor`** which inherits from **`AbstractUser`**. Despite entering the correct email and password during login, the system returns an "Invalid password" error.

base/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, Group, Permission

class Doctor(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Doctor')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    emp_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=150)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        blank=True,
        related_name='doctor_group'
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        blank=True,
        related_name='doctor_user_permission'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

base/views.py

```
def docter_login(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(email,password)
        # Authenticate the user using the email and password provided in the form
        
        if not Doctor.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'User with that email Does not exists.')
            return render(request, 'base/error.html')

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        
        
        if user is not None and user.is_doctor:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid password.')
            return render(request, 'base/error.html')
    return render(request, 'base/doctor_login.html')
```

the user exists and passing the correct credentials to authenticate, it's still returning "Invalid password". What could be causing this issue?
`

Comment: The `authenticate` does not work with `__iexact`... In fact, it works with `username` to identify the user.

Comment: Can you also share how you *registered* users, since the passwords need to be hashed for `authenticate` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The `authenticate` will not work, since by default it identifies a user with the `username`, and also does not perform an `__iexact` lookup.

We can [*write a custom authentication backend* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) to work with an email:

```
# app_name/authentication.py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend


class EmailAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = Doctor.objects.get(email__iexact=email, is_active=True)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None
```

and add this to the [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#authentication-backends):

```
# settings.py

# …

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['app_name.authentication.EmailAuthenticationBackend']
```

beware that when you *register* users, you should use `Doctor.objects.create_user(…)`.

I would also *not* say there is no user with that specific username, since then people can *guess* if a certain email address is registered as user: by just giving an error that the username/password combination is not valid, you thus do not expose information on what email addresses have registered users and which are not registered.